# Relations In Category Theory

Tags: ct.category-theory

Probably a silly question. Suppose that $C$ is a category that does not have finite Cartesian products. So we cannot define a relation on some objects to be a sub object of their Cartesian product (a monic arrow into their Cartesian product). Is there some other natural notion that we can use $inside$ the category to generalise the notion of `relation'? I'm not interested in using the concretisation, so let's suppose $C$ is not concrete.

Comment: By googling, I have found [Is there a standard notation for binary relations in category theory?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33978/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-binary-relations-in-category-theory).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could describe a relation between $X$ and $Y$ to be a pair of maps $f\colon R\to X$, $g\colon R\to Y$, so that the family of maps $\{f,g\}$ is monic (meaning, if $fh=fh'$ and $gh=gh'$, then $h=h'$.)

Comment: One also says "$f$ and $g$ are jointly monic"...

Comment: In fact, the above is the standard definition of an internal relation: an internal relation is a span of morphisms that are jointly mono. In case the category has binary products such relations can be represented as single monomorphisms into cartesian products. The latter definition is a bit less convenient to work with, but it is much easier to generalize it to non-canonical notions of subobjects, therefore some authors use it as their primary definition.

Comment: All this being said, it's hard to do much with relations in a category $C$ to simulate the usual sort of calculus of relations, unless one assumes more of $C$. For example, to get a half-decent notion of composition of relations, one typically assumes that $C$ is a regular category.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, but, actually, you do not have to assume that $C$ has products to define associative compositions (it suffices to assume that $C$ has pullbacks and stable images).

Comment: Of course not, @MichalR.Przybylek

Comment: There is a notion of "locally regular category", meaning one all of whose slice categories are regular, which behaves mostly like a regular category except that it doesn't have finite products.  It's just as good as a regular category for binary relations.

Comment: Just come back to needing to think about this a bit again. Just had a couple of questions. First, is FHILB, the category of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces and linear maps, locally regular? Secondly, what are the major parts of the usual calculus of relations that we can't recapture by working in locally regular categories?